# Changing position of element in vector container

Tags: c++, vector, insert, iterator

How to insert object which is pointed by it2 at the end of ktab?
I want to change current position of object in container to the latest one.

```
for(it2=ktab->begin(); it2!=ktab->end(); ){
    if(it2->KEY_r==key_w) {
        ktab->insert(ktab->end(), OBJECT POINTED by it2);
    }
    else
      ++it2;
 }
```

Comment: you want to insert a copy at end?

Comment: Exacly, I want do insert a copy at the end :)

Comment: Then, just `push_back` a copy?

Comment: `ktab->push_back(*it2)` or `ktab->emplace_back(*it2)` (depending on your requirements).

Answer (score 0):

to insert a copy at the `end()` do following:

```
it2=ktab->begin();
while ( it2!=ktab->end()) {
    if( it2->KEY_r==key_w) {
        ktab->push_back(*it2);
        break;
    } else {
      ++it2;
    }
}
```